# How to display Hindi Characters in rdlc report viewer in winform c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, entity-framework, rdlc

Please provide me the solution for this issue.

I have saved record in sql with hindi language, but when i display in rdlc report viewer it shows as a boxes.

1. SQL Database - I have saved record in hindi.

[image]

2. Service Code

   ```
    public class PaperRptModel
    {
        public string Subject { get; set; }
        public string Course { get; set; }
        public string Time { get; set; }
        public int MaxMarks { get; set; }
        public int PassMarks { get; set; }

        readonly PaperGenEntities paperGenEntities = new PaperGenEntities();

        public IList GetSingle(int Id)
        {
            List<PaperRptModel> paperRpts = new List<PaperRptModel>();
            PaperRptModel model = new PaperRptModel();
            var paper = paperGenEntities.Papers.FirstOrDefault(o => o.Id == Id);
            var subject = paperGenEntities.Subjects.FirstOrDefault(o => o.Id == paper.Subject);
            model.Course = $"{subject.EnglishCourse} ({subject.HindiCourse})";
            model.Subject = $"{subject.EnglishName} ({subject.HindiName})"; ;
            model.Time = paper.MaxTime;
            model.MaxMarks = paper.TotalMarks ?? 0;
            model.PassMarks = paper.PassMarks ?? 0;
            paperRpts.Add(model);
            return paperRpts;
        }

        public IList GetQuestions(int Id)
        {
            List<Question> questions = new List<Question>();
            Question model = new Question();
            var question = paperGenEntities.Questions.FirstOrDefault(o => o.Subject == Id);
            model.EnglishName = question.EnglishName;
            model.HindiName = question.HindiName;
            model.DisplayMarks = question.DisplayMarks;
            questions.Add(model);
            return questions;
        }
   ```
3. Window Form Code

   ```
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
            var rptModel = new PaperRptModel();
            var Model = rptModel.GetSingle(1);
            var rds1 = new ReportDataSource("DataSet1", Model);
            this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds1);

            var question = new Question();
            var questions = rptModel.GetQuestions(1);
            var rds2 = new ReportDataSource("DataSet2", questions);
            this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds2);
            this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
        }
    }
   ```
4. Result as boxes
   [image]

Comment: Encdoding is wrong.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2010/ms255056(v%3Dvs.100)

Comment: did you install the hindi language in your client computer?

Comment: i have install kruti dev font in system. When i have exported in word doc then i am getting hindi font, but in report viewer and pdf export getting blocks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you running this in a windows client

check whether you have installed the Hindi language

[image] (windows 10)

Comment: I guess this option for windows operating system language not for any specific application based language, but let me try this too. thanks

Comment: This is working. thank you, now i can see hindi words in Report viewer and Pdf as well.